# awk to combine and average matching fields

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to output data in the following format.

```
`$4` is `last # in `$6` that matches `$4` and maps to `$5` with an average depth of `average of $7` that matches `$4`
```

**input**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    1   20
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    2   20
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    3   22
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  1   201
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  2   201
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  3   201
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  4   202
```

**Desired output**

```
chr1:955543-955763 is 3 bases and maps to AGRN-6|gc=75 with an average  depth of 20.6
chr1:957571-957852 is 4 bases and maps to AGRN-7|gc=61.2 with an average depth of 201.3
```

I think this `awk` is close and hopefully a good start.  Thank you :).

```
awk '
    {N[$4]++
     T[$4]+=$6
     M[$4]=$7
    }
END     {for (X in N) printf ("%s is %d bases and maps to %s with an average depth"\
                            " of %f reads\n", X, N[X], M[X], T[X]/N[X]);
    }
'  input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: If youre going to wait until someone posts an answer based on your posted sample input/output and then say "oh no, there's more than 1 $4 value in my real input" then please don't - take the time now to edit your input and expected output to be more realistic. If not, then get rid of all the irrelevant text about "matching $4".

Comment: @Ed Morton there are many rows but I added another to the input and desired output, I apologize I was trying to keep the post small... Thank you :).

Comment: Brevity is never desirable in relation to software, conciseness is. It's good to have a small example but more importantly it's got to represent your requirements or it's practically useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a working prototype without formatting and words

```
$ awk '{k=$4 FS $5; a[k]+=$7; c[k]++} 
    END{for(k in a) 
          {split(k,ks,FS); 
           print ks[1],c[k],ks[2],a[k]/c[k]}}' file  

chr1:957571-957852 4 AGRN-7|gc=61.2 201.25
chr1:955543-955763 3 AGRN-6|gc=75 20.6667
```

add the missing words and do number formatting with printf if important.  `awk` shuffles the array and losing the order but there is a fix for it if you use `gawk`